# Синквейн или сенкан?

Tags: грамотная-речь, заимствования

В школе мы сочиняли только *сенкан*, и слово *синквейн* было мне вовсе неизвестно. Относительно недавно я, узнав это слово и его значение, решила порыться в Интернете — и увидела, что *синквейн* употребляют куда чаще, чем *сенкан*. Вопрос: какой вариант лучше? Или они равноправны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Википедия на украинском утверждает, что украинское "сенкан" по-русски звучит как "синквейн". Википедия на русском дает только "синквейн". В Нацкорпусе есть синквейн, но нет сенкана. Придумавшая эту поэтичскую форму американская поэтесса Аделаида Крэпси назвала ее Cinquain /ˈsɪŋkeɪn/. Я думаю, процесс словообразования закончен и новое слово скоро войдет в словари в написании "синквейн".